# Updating Angular 2 to Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to update my project from angular 2 to angular 4.

my package.json seems just like this:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
"@types/node": "^8.0.28",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
"angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
"applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.8",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
"css": "^2.2.1",
"css-loader": "^0.28.0",
"es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.10",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"file-loader": "^1.1.5",
"html-loader": "^0.5.1",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"js-beautify": "1.7.4",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"mydatepicker": "2.0.31",
"mydaterangepicker": "^4.1.9",
"ng2-nouislider": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
"node-sass": "^4.5.2",
"nouislider": "^10.1.0",
"preboot": "^5.1.4",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
"style-loader": "^0.19.0",
"tether": "^1.4.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"typescript": "^2.5.3",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.17"
```

but if I ran my project, I got this problem:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mydaterangepicker/bundles/mydaterangepicker.umd.js
```

Module not found : error : Can't resolve './directives/my-date-range-picker.focus.directive' in 'C:\VSTS****\WebApp\node_modules\mydaterangepicker\bundles' [C:\VSTS****\WebApp\FuelHubWeb.csproj]

```
   @ ./node_modules/mydaterangepicker/bundles/mydaterangepicker.umd.js 11:9-69
   @ ./ClientApp/src/modules/feature/seller/seller.module.ts
   @ ./ClientApp/src/modules/core/core-app/app-routing.module.ts
   @ ./ClientApp/src/modules/core/core-app/app.module.ts
   @ ./ClientApp/boot-server.ts 


 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/angular2-platform-node/node-platform.d.ts:1:10
      TS2305: Module '"C:/VSTS/****/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'.
```

Does anyone have some idea?

I have read a lot of website to try to solve this problem, but I can not find the right solution.

Best Regards,

Leon

Comment: are you using angular cli? systemjs?

Comment: Make sure you followed every single step stated in the updater: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @LLai; no, I don't use angular cli. and systemjs.

Comment: @Ploppy, I have done every single step, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try reinstalling all the packages, if you use NPM5 don't forget to remove both the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file.

Comment: @Ploppy I have deleted node_modules folder for many time and ran npm install, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you delete the package lock json file ?

Comment: @Ploppy, In my project, I can not find file called package lock json, only see package.json

Comment: @Ploppy Yes I have deleted package lock file.

Comment: Maybe mydaterangepicker is incompatible with the newer version of Angular.